# Listening to Ajax calls without typing additional code in the AJAX call iteslf

Tags: javascript, ajax, events

I was planning for a long time now to create a JS function that listens for failed AJAX calls and does something(like error reporting to a separate server).

I could call the function on the Ajax-failed portion of the AJAX code itself, but I want my colleagues to write AJAX calls without any need to remember that they need to type anything in the Ajax-failed portion.

e.g:

We code stuff like this:

- All the calls we want to handle errors for, go to pre-specified
  ajax_controller2.php. **So the file we target with our Ajax calls is
  ALWAYS called ajax_controller2.php**. There are other AJAX calls but
  to different php files and we don't want to handle errors for them.

> Is it possible to listen for failed AJAX calls only to a php file
>   called **ajax_controller2.php** without typing anything in the Ajax-failed
>   portion of the code?

The whole idea is that my colleagues just include a .js file in their HTML and the rest is done for them.

This is the AJAX calls we use:

```
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var params = //some parameters here;
        ajax.open("POST", "ajax_controller2.php?m=somecase", true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajax.send(params);
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var response = "";
            if (ajax.readyState == 1) {
                response += "Status 1: Server connection established ! <br/>";
            } else if (ajax.readyState == 2) {
                response += "Status 2: Request recieved ! <br/>";
            } else if (ajax.readyState == 3) {
                response += "Status 3: Processing Request ! <br/>";
            } else if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
                if (ajax.status == 200) {
                    var text = ajax.responseText;


                } else {
                    console.log("Ajax failed"); //In this portion of the code I could just type down the name of the function that when triggered, sends an error report.
                }
            }
        }
        //If an error occur during the ajax call.
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 404) {
            console.log("Error during AJAX call");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just write a wrapper function around the ajax logic that does the error handling and tell your colleagues to use that function instead of the "raw" ajax code? I'm not sure that this is the best question for SO, since you don't seem to have a specific problem or error. Try something out, and if it doesn't work, show what you tried and explain in what way it's not working.

Comment: The question states if it's possible to listen to ''raw'' ajax call failures without typing anything in the failed ajax code. This is the problem. I could just call an errorHandler() in the Ajax status 404. This is what I tried to solve my problem. I am asking to find other solutions too.

Comment: Right. And what I'm saying is that you could abstract the "core" functionality of the ajax request into some function (or class). You stated that you don't want other people to have to worry about calling the error handler.  This solution would accomplish that. Your question is along the lines of "Can I write a query without writing any SQL (or other popular query language)?" Simply put, no, you can't. But you can abstract away the query itself into a function so that, for example, you maybe only pass the table name and an ID (or something like that).

Comment: Ah, ok got it.  I used some time ago event dispatchers and event listeners - I just thought something similar could exist that doesn't need event dispatching - it just listens for a particular portion of code being run. This is what I had in mind when I asked this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also alter the prototype of XMLHttpRequest to also insert your event handler at the `onreadystatechange`.

In the code below I did that at the `open` method and using `addEventListener` so it won't mess or get lost with other event listeners even the ones added with `.onreadystatechange = function...`

```
    function errorLoggingFunc(){ console.log('myFunc'); };

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype._open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open= function(){
        if(!this._hasErrorLog)
        {
            this._hasErrorLog = true;
            this.addEventListener('readystatechange', errorLoggingFunc);  
        }

        this._open.apply(this, arguments);
    };
```

This way you colleagues will keep using the XMLHttpRequest but your logging will always be there anyway.